# Surehits leads - mobile optimized

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, responsive-design

can someone give me an idea on fixing, and getting surehits leads an mobile optimized, this means to use their mobile view... there is an option for that, but it seems do not work for me, cheers!

If someone faced the same proble, and have a solution for that i will be very happy!
The problem here is, that the feeds are displaying with a fixed width nomatter what is the size of the device. I found that, the provider (surehits) have an option `"ni_mobile = 1"`
Which should make the feeds mobile optimized, but it seems that its not working...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <title>Your Car Insurance Finders >> #1 Site to Compare, Select & Save Hundreds On Your Car Insurance...</title>
     </head>
     <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">           
            function getSuperClickVars(sc) {
                var __sc = '', temp="{";
                var a1 = sc.split('~');
                for (var i = 0; i < a1.length;i++) {
                    var s = a1[i].split('|');
                    temp += "\"" + s[0] + "\":\"" + s[1] + "\"";
                    if (i < a1.length-1) { temp += ","; }
                }
                temp += "}"
                __sc = eval('('+temp+')');
                return __sc;
             } 

             ni_ad_client = '15';
             ni_res_id = 2;
             ni_alt_url = "https://www.shmktpl.com/search.asp";
             ni_zc = '';
             ni_var1 = '';
             ni_max_display = -1;

             ni_mobile = 1;

             ni_color_border = '';
             ni_color_bg = "";
             ni_color_link = "";
             ni_size_link = 0;
             ni_color_url = "";
             ni_color_text = "";
             ni_height_hr = 2;
             ni_color_hr = "#084A8C";
    </script>
    <div id='foods'>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.shmktpl.com/retrieve_listings.asp"></script>    
        <noscript>
           <a href="https://www.shmktpl.com/search.asp?src=15&res=2">
               <img src="https://www.shmktpl.com/images/nojs/image.asp?src=15&res=2" border="0">
           </a>
        </noscript>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was fixed from the listing providers, they seems to had an mobile version of the script.